# Node-Redis psubscribe with custom messages

Tags: node.js, redis

I was under the impression that using this library:

https://github.com/mranney/node_redis

could do something like this:

```
var redis = require('redis');

var pub = redis.createClient();
var sub = redis.createClient();

sub.psubscribe('channel');

sub.on('message from channel', function(){});

pub.publish('channel','a message xyz');
```

the problem is that I can't seem to get the sub.on() to receive a specific custom message. The only entry point that seems to get fired is `sub.on('message')` or `sub.on('pmessage')`, but how can I get `sub.on('my custom message')` to get invoked? Hope this makes sense.

Comment: That's just not how that module works.  If you need that to happen, you'll have to write code to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just how the node redis client works. It reserves `message` and `pmessage` emit events for notifying you of `SUBSCRIBE` and `PSUBSCRIBE` events respectively.

https://github.com/mranney/node_redis#publish--subscribe

But if you want a syntax like what you have in your code you can always define your own message format and `EventEmitter`, something like this maybe:

```
var events = require('events');
var redis = require('redis');
var pub = redis.createClient();
var sub = redis.createClient();

var ee = new events.EventEmitter();

ee.on('aweomseEvent', function() {
    console.log('party!');
});

sub.on('subscribe', function() {
    var message = {
        type: 'aweomseEvent',
        isAwesome: true
    };
    pub.publish('mychannel', JSON.stringify(message));
});

sub.subscribe('mychannel');
sub.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    var deserialized = JSON.parse(message);
    if (deserialized.type) {
        ee.emit(deserialized.type, deserialized);
    }
});
```